Using a variable to access a form
So I have a function which populates a drop down list with the names of various departments.
The function gets passed the name of the form, and the control to which the drop down list applies.
I think I am nearly there with using the passed string within the function being turned into the form name, but can't get it to reference the control on the form correctly.
The Code is below
Public Function DeptList(ByVal myForm As String, ByVal myControl As String)
    Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim targetForm As Form = CType(asm.CreateInstance("Jigsaw2." & myForm), Form)
    SqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM Department WHERE Dept_Status = 'Active';"
    sql.ExecQuery(SqlTxt)
    Try
        For Each r As DataRow In sql.DBDT.Rows
            **[targetForm].DeptCombox.Items.Add(r("Dept_Name"))**
        Next
    Catch

    End Try


End Function

The sql works fine, its just the line in bold that I am having trouble with
Have searched through other solutions on stackoverflow, but they are either written in C, or do not fit the situation.

You should do better with naming things. That method should have a name that actually describes what it does. It appears that something like PopulateActiveDepartmentList. As for the parameters, formTypeName and controlName are actually descriptive of what those parameters contain. They don't contain your form or your control.

BTW, your method has no return type and it doesn't return anything, so it should be a Sub rather than a Function.

If an answer has resolved your issue then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way, everyone can see that you don't need any further assistance without even opening the question.

Every control, including forms, has a Controls collection property that allows you to index by the Name of the control. Assuming that you already have a Form reference and that your control will always be a ComboBox, you can do this:
Dim dropDownList = DirectCast(myForm.Controls(controlName), ComboBox)

dropDownList.DisplayMember = "Dept_Name"
dropDownList.DataSource = sql.DBDT.Rows

It's generally better to use data binding like this, rather than adding the items manually one by one. It may not work in this instance though, because I'm guessing that you're using a poorly implemented DAL and that DataTable will be reused. If that's not the case, you can safely bind it like I have, otherwise I'll leave it to you to decide how to actually populate the list.

Consider passing the combo box control to that routine.
So, say a simple form with a combo box, and we want to call a "general" routine to load up the values for that combo box.
Hence this code:
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    Call cboLoader(ComboBox1, strSQL)

And then in say our library code, we have this routine:
Public Sub cboLoader(cbo As ComboBox, strSQL As String)

    Dim rstResult As New DataTable

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstResult.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    cbo.DataSource = rstResult

End Sub

So, note how we don't have to pass the form name, or the control name, but we just pass the control object.
Hence this for a test:

So, in most cases, you don't even have to pass the form name and control, but pass a reference of the combo box to some general routine should suffice.
